# mashed potatoes - fixing undercooked potatoes

Tags: potatoes, mash

1. I decided to do  mashed potatoes.
2. I boiled the potatoes (needed 3-5 min more, the were in about 30 min)
3. I just realised they're undercooked
4. I  cut the potatoes into smaller pieces (2-3 cm chunks) and put them in the warm pan that I used to boil them

What should I do now. Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest microwaving them on to complete the cooking without getting them waterlogged, unless you have a huge volume of potatoes.   They should still be quite hot from the previous cooking, so should not take long to begin cooking in the microwave.

If you don't have a microwave, you could try continuing to boil them, but you don't want to add cold water and have the starches begin to crystallize, so I would try to keep them as warm as reasonably possible while bringing the water to a boil in an electric kettle or another pot.

Comment: Since mashed potatoes are the goal, it's likely that the final product will include butter and milk/cream too. Whether it is done in the microwave, on the stovetop, or in the oven, there is no reason not to bring those ingredients on board. The OP could just simmer or bake (or microwave) the underdone potatoes in the dairy.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is timely, but I did the same thing and just mashed them best I could anyways. They did remain a little lumpy but I added melted butter, about half a stick to start, then a scrambled egg yolk in half & half then more butter and half & half as I folded and mashed the potatoes. Like I said, some slightly lumpy bits, but overall still really good.

I think that just call that country style mashed potatoes, when you still have potato bits in them.

Answer (score 0):

I always use steam pressure cooker for potatoes. They are ready in just 10-12 min. and never come out under cooked. Best of all, they keep way more nutritional value this way.

Pro tip: cook your potatoes with a sliced onion for better taste and flavor.